# How to make the button's height change automatically depending on the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-relativelayout

I've 3 buttons which are below an imageview, but i want them to change their height automatically depending on the screen ratio/size.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main3Activity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="133dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="133dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
        android:text="Button1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="36dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="184dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/button1"
        android:text="Button2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="260dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/button2"
        android:text="Button3"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="340dp" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what it looks like, in a 6" screen and in a 5":
[image]

[image]

and here i leave you an edited image about how i want it to look like:

[image]

[image]

Thanks for your help.
(i think that using match_parent in layout_height will be the solution, but i have tried and i don't know how to use it)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a `LinearLayout` and set equal weight to all 3 buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Main3Activity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="133dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Button3"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout or TableLayout and make all buttons heights *match_parent* then give all buttons **weight** property

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```